# Zend Framework Custom filter in own libary directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, filter

I'm trying to make my custom filter work...

I have the following code in my AuthController:

```
<?php
public function loginAction()
{
    // Get db var
    $db = $this->_getParam('db');

    // Load loginform
    $loginForm = new Application_Form_Auth_Login();

    // Form posted?
    if ($loginForm->isValid($_POST))
    {
        // Setup adapter
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
          $db,
          'users',
          'username',
          'password'
          );

        // Set identity and credential
        $adapter->setIdentity($loginForm->getValue('username'));
        $adapter->setCredential($loginForm->getValue('password'));

        // Setup Zend_Auth and try to authenticate the user
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        // If authentication succeed
        if ($result->isValid())
        {
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Inloggen geslaagd');
            $this->_redirect('/');
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Inloggen geslaagd');
        }
    }

    $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;
}
?>
```

The code of the form is:

```
<?php
class Application_Form_Auth_Login extends Zend_Form
{
  /**
   * Default_Form_Auth_Login::init()
   * 
   * Form which authenticates guests
   * 
   * @return void
   */
  public function init()
  {    
    $this->setMethod('post');    

    $this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
        'label' => 'Gebruikersnaam:',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
      ));

    $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
      'label' => 'Wachtwoord:',
      'required' => true,
      'filters' => array('Pcw_Filter_Hash')
      ));

    $this->addElement('hash', 'formToken', array(
      'salt' => 'unique'
      ));

    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
      'ignore' => true,
      'label' => 'Inloggen',
      )); 

  }  
}
```

The code of my custom filter is:

```
<?php

class Pcw_Filter_Hash implements Zend_Filter_interface
{
  /**
   * HashFilter::filter()
   * 
   * @param string $value
   * @return
   */
  public function filter($value)
  {
    return hash('sha512', $value);
  }  
}
```

When using it this way I keep getting this message:
Message: Plugin by name 'Pcw_Filter_Hash' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Filter_: Zend/Filter/

I have found documentation about setting namespaces and adding paths but I can't get anything to work...

Does anyone has a working solution for my problem? This will be highly apprectiated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather rewrite you form elements like this one :

```
$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password("password");
$password->setLabel("Wachtwoord")
         ->setRequired(true); 

$password->addFilter(new  Pcw_Filter_Hash() );
```

but I am not sure this might work :

```
$this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
      'label' => 'Wachtwoord:',
      'required' => true,
      'filters' => array(new Pcw_Filter_Hash())
      ));
```

and you should double check that `Pcw` is defined in `application.ini`

I hope your problem get solved soon :)

Comment: Thank you, but defining Pcw in application.ini did not work for me..
This did work: Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance(); $loader->registerNamespace('Pcw_'); 

I did copy your style of writing my form elements.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the path to your filter in your from

```
<?php
class Application_Form_Auth_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {    
        // add the path where own filters are located
        $this->addElementPrefixPath(
            'Pcw_Filter',
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Pwc/Filter',
            'filter'
        );

        $this->setMethod('post');

        ...
    }
}
```

Maybe you have to change the path to fit your own layout of your application.

Comment: Solution:        
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('Pcw_');

Answer (score 2):

in you application.ini add this line `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Pcw_"` next make sure the file is named `Hash.php` and that it lives at `/application/libray/Pcw/Filter` and the class name needs to remain `Pcw_Filter_Hash` if you do that the autoloader should find it.